# Installing Rails on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby, rails

I tried installing `rails` according  to [this guide](http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu), and when I do, I get this error:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
  WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getaddrinfo (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
  WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getaddrinfo (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing rails:
      ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

          /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
      from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
      from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


  Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-  1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I've never seen anything like this before, so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install Ruby, then Gem and then install Rails. Problem maybe is on Ruby or Gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rvm` or `rbenv`; they both works great... I personally prefer rvm because I want to keep gem-sets separate for different projects. See  [rbenv repository](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) if you want to simple installation just using one ruby version. I've written a blog post on [Rbenv Installation](http://www.computersnyou.com/1535/2013/03/installing-ruby-on-rail-on-ubuntu-with-rbenv-step-by-step/)

---

1. Installing rbenv

   Setup:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   ```

   Install required components for Ruby and other dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git-core -y
   sudo apt-get install curl -y
   sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev libgdbm-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config libffi-dev
   git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
   echo ‘export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"’ >> ~/.profile
   echo ‘eval "$(rbenv init -)"’ >> ~/.profile
   ```

   (Note: modify .bash_profile , .bash_login or .zshrc according to your needs.)

   Now install some required rbenv plugins.

   ```
   cd  ~/.rbenv/
   mkdir plugins
   cd  ~/.rbenv/plugins
   git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
   ```

   Restart the terminal.
2. Installing Ruby

   ```
   rbenv  install 1.9.3-p385
   ```

   Set your global Ruby version.

   ```
   rbenv global 1.9.3-p385
   rbenv rehash
   ruby -v
   ```
3. Install Ruby on Rails Framework

   ```
   gem install bundler
   gem install rails
   ```

   (Don't panic, installing rails will take some time.)